# What is the use of globals() in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, global-variables

```
d={}
for x in range(5):
        globals()['int%s' % x] = int(input("Enter the marks of the students: "))
a = int0 + int1 + int2 + int3 + int4
print ("The average marks are ", a/5)
```

I don't understand the use of dictionary, `globals()` and `['int%s' % x]` in this code. I'm very new to Python, and programming in general, so it would be very much appreciated if someone could answer this in a very simple language.

Thank you so much.

Comment: In this code `globals()` has been used because the person writing it has not yet figured out how lists work.

Comment: Do not follow the example of this code. It is of very poor quality, abusing the global namespace because the author does not seem to understand the built in Python data structures. If someone wrote this at an interview, they would certainly not be hired

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, that's the twisted and worst code to learn any language I saw... I mean, if you are learning the first principles don't look at it for too long right now. When you get more practice, review this. That's just an advice. Anyway, I will explain to you line by line:

```
d={}

'''
here declares a variable with name d, and saves an empty dictionary to it... 
I don't know why, because it is never used
'''

for x in range(5):
    globals()['int%s' % x] = int(input("Enter the marks of the students: "))

'''
this is a loop that will be repeated 5 times, globals() is a dictionary 
of all the variables in the scope that are alive with in the program... 
so, globals()['int%s' % x] is creating a new key-value,
for example {'int0': 4}. It is a way to dynamically create variables, so, 
the x will have the values [0,1,2,3,4], that's why the variables
will have the names int0, int1, int2, int3, int4.
Finally, it ask to the user to type a number, 
and this number will be stored in one of those variables, 
then the maths:
'''


a = int0 + int1 + int2 + int3 + int4
'''sum all the inputs from the user'''
print ("The average marks are ", a/5) 
#divide it by 5
```

> A posible way to achieve the same, but a little more generalized:

```
total=0
numberOfMarks = 5
for x in range(numberOfMarks):
  mark = input("Enter the marks of the students: ")
  while(not mark or not mark.isdigit()):
    print("please, enter a number value representin the mark")
    mark = (input("Enter the marks of the students: "))

  total += int(mark)

print ("The average marks are ", total/numberOfMarks)
```